# Math.random() not giving unique number; is there any issue in API?

Tags: java

`Math.random()` not working properly. Can you please help me to fix this issue?

```
public class MethodTest {
 static Set<Long>dups=new HashSet<Long>();
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 while(true){
     long value=    (long) (Math.random() * 1000000000l);
     if(dups.add(value)){
         System.out.println(value);
     } else{
         System.out.println("Dup "+value);
         break;
     }
 }

}

}
```

Comment: `not working properly` ? What does that mean?

Comment: Math. random is not for generating unique numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Random numbers aren't guaranteed to be distinct.

Think about rolling a dice: you're going to roll the same number twice if you keep rolling it repeatedly. Once you've rolled a 6-sided dice 7 times, it is impossible *not* to have a duplicate.

Randomness isn't about whether the value is distinct - it is the property that *all* values could be obtained with equal probability on each roll. If you can't roll numbers you've seen before, this decreases the probability of those numbers occurring again (to zero), whilst increasing the probability of numbers you've not seen before.

The consequence of the non-uniqueness is sometimes called the [Birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox) - which gives the somewhat surprising result that you only need 23 people in a room before it is more likely than not that 2 people share a birthday.

According to the birthday paradox, one would expect your code to be more likely than not to have found a duplicate by (roughly) `sqrt(1_000_000_000) = 10^4.5 ~= 30k` iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Math.random() function not guaranteed to unique value.
your program is terminated at duplicate value.

If you want unique value call the random function once again if you found duplicate value.
Some what like this.

```
public class Main {
    static Set<Long> uniqueValues = new HashSet<Long>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Unique Value is: "+getUniqueValue());
        }
    }

    public static long getUniqueValue() {
        boolean isUnique = false;
        long value = 0;
        while (!isUnique) {
            value=(long) (Math.random() * 1000000000l);
            isUnique = uniqueValues.add(value);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that it takes an increasingly long time to return a value - and eventually, it never returns. A better approach is to fill a list with all the possible values in sequence and shuffle it, then just keep an iterator for that list - you then get constant time access, and can detect when there are no more unique values to be found.

Comment: (Although you might not want to do that for 1B possible values, since you'd need a list of that many Integer instances, which would consume an awful lot of ram).

Answer (score 0):

You will get duplicates because if you have a limited pool of numbers to choose from you will eventually end up choosing the same number twice.

Lets say you had a hat with the numbers 1 to 10 on separate pieces of paper.
You decide to choose a number. Look at it. Place it back in the hat. Then choose another number....... Keep going and the probability of choosing the same number twice before you have picked all unique numbers gets higher and higher.

You could check the number in the following line of code..

```
if(dups.add(value)){
  System.out.println(value);
} else{
  System.out.println("Dup "+value);
  continue;
}
```

This would go to the next iteration of the loop and you would end up filling the HashSet to the brim but... you would also need to check the size of the hash set to make sure you now have all the unique numbers. So lets say you have a range of 0 - 10 then you would need to do something along the lines of...

```
long max = 10;

if(dups.add(value)){
  System.out.println(value);
} else{
  System.out.println("Dup "+value);
  if (dups.size() == max) {
    break;
  }
  continue;
}
```

if you want a value between a range then you have to do something along the lines of

```
int min = 0;
int max = 10;
int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
```

So for your full solution you would need....

```
public class MethodTest {
   static Set<Long>dups=new HashSet<Long>();
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   long value;
   long min = 0;
   long max = 10;
   while(true) {
     value = (long) rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
     if(dups.add(value)){
       System.out.println(value);
     } else{
       System.out.println("Dup "+value);
       break;
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate a unique no first you create a list with all possible no and then suffle it.
then you can read it with iterator or other methoda as you want.